# Can access ViewField from mapped classe in Flask

Tags: python, couchdb, flask

I have a ViewField in my mapped class.

```
class Keyword(Document):
    doc_type = 'keyword'

    content=TextField()
    search =  ViewField(
        'docs', "function(doc) {\
            if(doc.doc_type == 'keyword') {\
                if(doc.content == content) {\
                    emit(doc.id, doc);
                }\
            }\
        }"
    )
```

In my blueprint I want to iterate over all keywords with certain content.

```
blueprint = Blueprint('keywords', __name__)

@blueprint.route('/keywords')
def handle_keywords():
    for keyword in Keyword.search['name']:
        print keyword
```

My app.py setup.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(keywords.blueprint)

manager = CouchDBManager()
manager.setup(app)

manager.add_document(Keyword)
server = Server()

manager.sync(app)
```

But I get an error `Keyword doesn't have attribute 'search'`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In `handle_keywords()`, you probably want to do this instead:

```
Keyword.search(db, 'name')
```

(I'm not sure where you'd get the db from in the context of Flask; this is just from my reading of the CouchDB-Python sources, which is what Flask-CouchDB uses under the covers.)